# How can I load the image from external folder in SASS as a background image?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, sass

I have a scenario where all of my images will be loading from the third party cloud library and not my local root folder, is there any way I can configure that path in SASS and set them as URL for the background-image?

This is what I have currently:
$placeholder-image: url('../../img/test.png');

But the img folder is not available at it's given path, it should still be able to load the images. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about rewriting your relative paths - that would require some kind of SCSS parser plugin. Probably more effort than its worth if you have control of the stylesheets.

More simply, you could set a variable which is the URL to wherever your images are served from, then interpolate that with the path to an image, all inside a function for convenience.

Like so:

```
$bg-image-url: 'https://image-server.com/';

@function bgImageUrl($path) {
  @return url('#{$bg-image-url}#{$path}');
}

.element {
  background-image: bgImageUrl('test.png');
}
```

Compiles to:

```
.element {
  background-image: url("https://image-server.com/test.png");
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding. In my case $bg-image-url path, need to be loaded from the JSON, I tried writing that function in SASS but didn't seem to support that, can you please let me know if there's anyway to make that possible?